# Why is it not possible to ping a local IP when connected to Mozilla VPN?

Tags: vpn, ping

OS is Windows 10 and there are 5 network interfaces:

```
Mozilla VPN
IP 10.109.17.243
Subnet mask 255.255.255.255
Default gateway 0.0.0.0

WiFi 1 not connected

WiFi 2 not connected

WiFi 3
IP 192.168.178.38
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway 192.168.178.1

Bluetooth ethernet not connected
```

The printer IP is 192.168.178.39. I tried to ping it and it immedietly returns saying there is an error. Something like "general error". With the VPN disabled ping works.
Unfortunately it was a client of mine and I cannot provide any further information because I am no longer at his PC.

I think ping should be no problem because Windows should know it has to use interface WiFi 3 for this subnet.

It is also strange that the MozillaVPN interface has 0.0.0.0 as default gateway and 255.255.255.255 as subnet mask. I think these are not valid values.

Any ideas why the ping fails?

Comment: Probably some type of VPN kill switch.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you I googled for it and I think this could be the cause.

Comment: But a killswitch is said to prevent internet access. Why should it block a local IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to configure split tunneling. For Mozilla VPN there is a [support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/i-cant-print-wirelessly-when-mozilla-vpn) explaining how to allow local network access to enable wireless printing:

> 1. Open Mozilla VPN and turn it off if it's not already.
> 2. Click the Settings vpn settings icon icon.
> 3. Select Network settings.
> 4. Put a check next to Local network access.
> 5. Turn Mozilla VPN back on.

Comment: I already knew that help page but didn't read it right. Thanks...

Comment: @somega That is unfortunate. It had the exact problem you've described in the title and you've still decided you are unable to find a solution yourself.

Comment: Sorry don't know what you mean. But now it's working. All good.